# macos ${{ env.TMPDIR }} not working in github actions

Tags: macos, github-actions

I have a github action which tries to use ${{ env.TMPDIR }} and that doesnt appear to expand to the TMPDIR environment variable.

```
 - name: DEBUG Workaround GitHub-Actions-MacOS Issue with env.TMPDIR
    run: |
      echo "TMPDIR=$TMPDIR"
      echo "TMPDIR using ENV.TMPDIR=${{ env.TMPDIR }}"
```

this produces:

```
TMPDIR=/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/
TMPDIR using ENV.TMPDIR=
```

EXAMPLE:
[DEBUG Workaround GitHub-Actions-MacOS Issue with env.TMPDIR](https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/runs/1508428339?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: You would reference a bash environment variable with `$TMPDIR`, which you've done.  You would reference a GitHub Actions variable with the `${{ env... }}` context syntax.  But this is not a GitHub Actions variable.  Why are you trying to use `${{ env.TMPDIR }}` here?  I feel like you're not explaining what you're trying to do.

Comment: This was TEST code. I was trying to use the ${{ env.TMPDIR}} in the specification of where I was UPLOADING files in another rule. But I couldn't print out why that was failing. Thats why I added this code to be able to dump the value of variables.

Comment: see the link https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/actions/runs/404926809/workflow   at the end. I was trying to use it in the WITH statement trying to specify a folder to copy to.

Answer (score 7):

`TMPDIR` is a *shell* environment variable provided by bash.  You're referring to it correctly with `$TMPDIR`, which is how you reference an environment variable in bash.  It will probably resolve to something like `/tmp`.

However, you cannot set a shell environment variable in one step of your GitHub Actions workflow, and then use it in another.  That's because you'll get a new instance of a shell, and it will have a new environment.  This will not work:

```yaml
- run: FOO="hello"
- run: echo $FOO
```

However, you can use a [GitHub Actions environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables) to persist information in the GitHub Actions environment, instead of in the shell environment.  These are two different things, and there's no implicit mixing.  That is to say `$TMPDIR` is not `${{env.TMPDIR}}`.  These are two *different* environments.

If you want to persist an environment variable between steps, you will need to *set it* explicitly, and then you can use it.  (Your workflow is not setting the `TMPDIR` anywhere.)

(I would also encourage you to use a different name, to avoid confusion with the `TMPDIR` environment variable set by your shell.)

You can [set a GitHub Actions environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) by `echo`ing a `name=value` pair to a specific file provided to you in a shell environment variable.

In other words:

```yaml
- run: echo "FOO=hello" >> $GITHUB_ENV
- run: echo ${{ env.FOO }}
```

Will persist the GitHub Actions environment variable `FOO` with the value `hello`.  The second run step will print it.

If you want to create, persist and use a temporary directory, you should use the `mktemp` command.  For example, to create a temp directory in one step and set its path to the `TEMP_DIR` environment variable, write a file into the temp dir in the next step, print the temp directory name in a third step, and show the contents in a final step:

```yaml
- run: echo "TEMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
- run: echo "hi" >> ${{ env.TEMP_DIR}}/temp_file
- run: echo ${{env.TEMP_DIR}}
- run: ls -Flas ${{ env.TEMP_DIR }}
```

If you really want to use `TMPDIR` (and again, I don't think that you should) then you'll need to set *it* as a GitHub Actions environment variable.

```yaml
- run: echo $TMPDIR # works
- run: echo ${{ env.TMPDIR }} # does not work
- run: echo "TMPDIR=${TMPDIR}" >> $GITHUB_ENV # sets it into the GitHub Actions environment
- run: echo ${{ env.TMPDIR }} # works
```

Comment: MacOS has an environment variable called TMPDIR. This is the equivilent of /tmp is most unixes. I have temporary files that get written there. I'm trying to copy those out as build artifacts (as you can see in the example referenced in the original question).     I'm trying to access that folder name from the archive rule.

Comment: name: Archive Log Results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Log Results (${{ matrix.displayTargetName }})
          path: |
            Builds/${{ matrix.config_name }}/PerformanceDump.txt
            /tmp/LOGS-ARCHIVE
            #${{ env.TMPDIR }}/Trace*.txt

Comment: workaround was to do the copy in the SHELL (where i can see the environment variable) to a known hardwired location. But I'd like to not have to do that extra copy, and just upload from the macos /tmp direcotry (whihc is named by an environment variable).

Comment: Again, the environment variable that your *shell* sets has no bearing on GitHub Actions.  You cannot use `${{ env.TMPDIR }}`.

Comment: If you want to use `${{ env.TMPDIR }}`, do the thing that I answered and set the shell's `TMPDIR` as a _GitHub Actions_ environment variable.

Comment: In the macos shell, $TMPDIR expands to an ENVIRONMENT variable. Like as in https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html.  That environment variable is NOT the same as a shell variable (which is a variable and syntactically like an enviroment variable in the shell language). One way you can tell its an environment variable and not a shell variable, is with PRINTENV TMPDIR

Comment: Then comes the question of who sets it. Sure - its possible it gets set by bash (or whatever shell you are using on MacOS). I know that when I run any programs from a github action, its already set by the time they run, which means its either set in the github action process, or whatever it invokes to invoke other programs (probably the shell). I dont know for sure, but I suspect its alerady set in github actions. Perhaps you are tryning to say that this ENVIRONEMENT variable (not shell variable) is set by the shell itself; that would explain the behavior.

Comment: Again.  I'm trying to say that an environment variable (man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) has nothing to do with GitHub Actions.  A _GitHub Actions environment variable_ is a completely separate thing.  Unless you _explicitly set one_, you cannot _use one_.  So _set one_ in one run step, then you can _use it_ in another.

Comment: Are you saying that "github action environment variables aren't environment variables"? That would imply a poor name choice for the feature. Its also pretty clearly untrue from my testing. You CAN in fact (as one would expect) access using $ syntax github environment variables from subshells (and that means they are implemented as true environment variablles).

Comment: It MAYBE (and if so its a sad and queer choice) - that the set of github action environment variables - while USED TO POPLUATE the environemnt of tasks it invokes, is perhaps not INITIALIZED from the set of system environment variables. THAT would explain the behavior I'm seeing, but I would suggest if that is the case its either a bug or poor design choice.

Comment: There is sense and utility in allowing access to predefined system environemnt variables (like TMPDIR, or PATH) from within the action script, and as you point out, you can always do it anyhow (by writing scripts that run and add to the github actions environment variables). It would be best if the github actions STARTED from the set of environment variables that process inherits, rather than from its own set of variables, and then MERGING those into the environment when it fork/execs subprocesses.

Comment: I really don't know what you're talking about.  GitHub Actions gives you a place to store key/value pairs that persist between runs.  They're stored in the GitHub Actions environment.  These have nothing to do with the environment variables like `TMPDIR` or `PATH`.  Nothing at all.  They are completely unrelated.

Comment: I'm suggesting that they SHOULD be exported as part of the environment (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) and should be INHERIT (default to) the values from the process environment variables. As near as I can tell, you already DO the former, and I'm suggesting also doing the later.

Comment: And if you believe that github action environment variables are NOT automatically exported to subprocesses as environment variables, please explain how <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/v2.1-Release/.github/workflows/build-N-test-Windows-v2.1-Dev.yml> use of $MAKEFLAGS works. It would appear this is being set using the github action :env mechanism, and is making into the run subshells as environment variablles.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying, just that you need to set it explicitly, either in the `env` section or by appending to the `$GITHUB_ENV`.

Comment: In case I'm not perfectly clear, the documentation (though it doesnt say this explicitly) SUGGESTS/HINTS that github environment varaibles ARE regular POSIX environment variables. When you set them, they appear in subprocesses as environment variables. The docs dont make clear any DISTINCTION or EXCEPTION to their being environment variables, and they call them ENVIRONEMNT variables.  All I'm saying is - if you insist they are VERY different (or in any way different) - it owuld be good for the docs to say how. And I'd say much better - DONT THINK OF THEM AS DIFFERENT. MAKE THEM IDENTICAL.